# Mathplotlib xticks not appearing (((

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, xticks

Please help me to understand why the labels don't appear under my chart.
It has to appear for example like "2022-11-01", "2022-11-02", "2022-11-03" etc.
And if array with dates are too big then it have to automatically show for example like "2022-11-01", "2022-11-25", "2022-12-20".....
Here is the code what I wrote for now:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(16, 10), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [2, 1]})
    ax1.grid()
    ax2.grid()
    dt_profits['res_5'].plot(ax=ax1, legend=True, marker='^', ylabel="Сумма в рублях",
                                        title='Прибыль/убытки')
    dt_profits['res_6'].plot(ax=ax1, legend=True)
    dt_profits['res_7'].plot(ax=ax1, legend=True)
    dt_profits['res_5'].plot(ax=ax2, legend=True, grid=True, marker='^',
                                     ylabel="Сумма в рублях", linestyle='--')
    dt_profits['res_6'].plot(ax=ax2, legend=True, linestyle='--')
    dt_profits['res_7'].plot(ax=ax2, legend=True, linestyle='--', xlabel='Дата')
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
    ax1.grid(which='major', color = 'k', linestyle = ':')
    ax2.grid(which='major', color = 'k', linestyle = ':')
        
    ax1.tick_params(axis = 'x',    #  Применяем параметры к обеим осям
               which = 'minor',    #  Применяем параметры к вспомогательным делениям
               direction = 'out',    #  Рисуем деления внутри и снаружи графика
               length = 3,    #  Длинна делений
               width = 2,     #  Ширина делений
               pad = 5,    #  Расстояние между черточкой и ее подписью
               labelsize = 10,    #  Размер подписи
               bottom = True)    #  Рисуем метки снизу
    ax1.tick_params(axis = 'x',    #  Применяем параметры к обеим осям
               which = 'major',    #  Применяем параметры к вспомогательным делениям
               direction = 'out',    #  Рисуем деления внутри и снаружи графика
               length = 5,    #  Длинна делений
               width = 2,     #  Ширина делений
               pad = 5,    #  Расстояние между черточкой и ее подписью
               labelsize = 10,    #  Размер подписи
               bottom = True)    #  Рисуем метки снизу
    ax2.tick_params(axis = 'x',    #  Применяем параметры к обеим осям
               which = 'minor',    #  Применяем параметры к вспомогательным делениям
               direction = 'out',    #  Рисуем деления внутри и снаружи графика
               length = 3,    #  Длинна делений
               width = 2,     #  Ширина делений
               pad = 5,    #  Расстояние между черточкой и ее подписью
               labelsize = 10,    #  Размер подписи
               bottom = True)    #  Рисуем метки снизу
    ax2.tick_params(axis = 'x',    #  Применяем параметры к обеим осям
               which = 'major',    #  Применяем параметры к вспомогательным делениям
               direction = 'out',    #  Рисуем деления внутри и снаружи графика
               length = 5,    #  Длинна делений
               width = 2,     #  Ширина делений
               pad = 5,    #  Расстояние между черточкой и ее подписью
               labelsize = 10,    #  Размер подписи
               bottom = True)    #  Рисуем метки снизу
    ax1.set_xticks(dt_profits.index)
    ax2.set_xticks(dt_profits.index)
    plt.show()
```

nothing helps. tried set_major_locator. it doesn't help too

Comment: Did you try removing `ax1.set_xticks(dt_profits.index)`? `set_xticks()` needs a list of positions and optionally a list of labels.  Did you try to convert your index from string format to datetime format?

Comment: We have dates in index in datetime format already! And without set_xticks(dt_profits.index) we have number of day on axis "X" every seven tick. But other ticks are not signed !

Comment: Also when we add ax1.minorticks_on() - all of the minor grid signs disappearing

Comment: As I can understand now it automatically uses my datetime index, making month as major ticks and days as minor ticks. And I don't understand how to change it

Comment: See e.g [Major tick every month and minor tick every week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469640/major-tick-every-month-and-minor-tick-every-week-in-matplotlib).  `ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.dates.DayLocator(interval=1))`

Comment: this way doesn't work too:    ax1.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%y.%m.%d'))